# Makefile variables from command line vs. environment

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to detect whether a variable has been set from the environment vs. on the command line?

I would like to distinguish between someone invoking make with `make LIB=mylib` vs. `make` and $LIB being defined.

Comment: Please, tag your make-related questions with [make] tag.  For rationale see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24030/why-do-they-specify-makefile-tag-instead-of-make/26567#26567

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can use the [origin](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Origin-Function) function to determine where a variable was defined.

```
ifneq (,$(findstring environment,$(origin LIB)))
    # LIB was defined by the environment
else
    # LIB was defined some other way
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

With non-Gnu make, you could run the `export` command and `grep` for the variable in question. This works only in rules and only as long as the variable is not set as a one-shot (like in `LIB=foo make`).